# What is the purpose of Large Gems?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

There are the large gems you get from 15 gems of any kind.

Do they serve any real purpose? What is "capture the gem"?

Comment: Arqade won't let me just use the title Terraria: Large Gems. I must use purpose at the end. Because of quality.

Comment: There's no need to put "Terraria" in the title as that's what the tag is for.

Comment: @Kitkat3547 Because that's a bad title? Try phrasing your question as, eh, a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Large gems cannot be placed or used to make anything else, they cannot be sold for any value which means they have no real function.

When a player carries a large gem a hologram of that gem appears above their head. Upon death a player will drop any large gems that they are carrying.

This means that their sole purpose is for the PvP game "Capture the Gem", in which teams of players attempt to steal the enemy's Large Gem and bring it back to their base.